Subscription consumption from GCP extremely slow
I have about 10K messages sitting in the topic/subscription.
Here is the code I am using.
Properties set for concurrency:
    spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.executor-threads=20
    spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.parallel-pull-count=4

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapterTry(
            @Qualifier("tryInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(
                pubSubTemplate, tryConfig.getSubscription());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setPayloadType(tryClass.class);
        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tryInputChannel")
    public void MessageReceiver(tryClass tryMessage, @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE)
    BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message, @Headers Map<String, Object> headerMap) {
        log.info("About to go async");
        asyncProcessor(tryMessage, message);
        log.info("Async processor is working");
    }

   private void asyncProcessor(tryClass tryMessage, BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message) {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            log.info("Process in Async Fashion");
            // Do heavy lifting here that can take 20ish seconds to consume tryMessage
        }

   }

The processing is so slow that the log `Process in Async Fashion` appears once every many seconds. The delta time between each log varies and can be upto 30 seconds. I have never seen them back to back. 

What is the issue here for slowness?
Another worry I have is that my handler just calls "asyncProcessor" and the Future might run on some other Executor and wont be limited by above to properties that restricts to `20x4=80` based on my config? I am afraid eventually it can cause out of memory? Or the 80 limit will be honored until my 80 asyncProcessor finish? I know I can set 
`spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscription.[subscription-name].flow-control.max-outstanding-element-count=<count>`
Do I need that?
But my primary worry is the slowness


I guess it's a pull subscription, correct? On which service is running your java code?

I am not sure why you say guess it is pull. As far as I understand, this is not a pull, this is streaming.

Sure, I was speaking about the PubSub subscription type. Anyway, where are you hosting your code?

This is hosted on a K8 cluster. I can share the requested and limit numbers for CPU memory that K8 will let my pod have if that is required. The JSON is not that small, it can be upto 40Megs and I bring it all in memory

40Mb? Are you sending it compressed? If you have slowness, I think it's at network layers to look at.
